# Convert value to as many decimal places in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, floating-point

I have string which has a double values as `2.344`.Now i want to have as many decimal places for this number as i get from server.So i `maxdecimalPlaces` is `2` then i want to have number as `2.34` if `maxdecimalplaces` is `3` then i want to have number as `2.344`.

I don't want to use `[NSString StringwithFormat:@"%.2f",value];`
because number of decimal places is dynamic.Please tell how can i resolve this issue,

Comment: Use NSNumberFormatter.

Comment: Please provide the code

Comment: @iOSGuy - your problem is solved or not

Answer (score 2):

> i maxdecimalPlaces is 2 then i want to have number as 2.34 if maxdecimalplaces is 3 then i want to have number as 2.344

use `setMaximumFractionDigits:` and pass the  maxdecimalPlaces

```
  float inputValue = 2.344;
 NSNumberFormatter *Formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
 [Formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
 [Formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:maxdecimalPlaces];  
 NSString *finalOutput = [Formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:inputValue]];
 NSLog(@"finalOutput: %@", finalOutput)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how use `NSNumberFormatter`

```
        NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2;
        NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:@(0.3333)]); // output expected .33
```

Hope it helps you.